# Children's horror story where there are cold spots in a garden where someone is stealing life force

Tags: story-identification, books, horror, childrens-novel

I am looking to get the name of a children's horror story (might be an RL Stine or similar kind of book) where there are cold spots in a garden where someone (or maybe something) is stealing life force from bugs, then animals, then finally from humans in an effort to stay alive or young. They are doing this by touching the said alive item.

The book is a short novel and I read it in the nineties, so would be from the eighties or early nineties at the latest.

Anyone have an idea of the name of this book?